# Chart.js Draw grid lines inside or over the polar points

Tags: chart.js

Looking for a solution to get the grid lines inside or over the polar area points.
Like the image attached.
I found the code which draws the gridLines and the one draws the point.
I also see it's possible to pass a creationPattern() as background.
But I don't know how to get them working together.

Maybe a solution can be simply show the gridLines over the points and not behind.

[image: example chart]

Comment: Like your graph. Guessing you dont have an open source project? :)